# NodeJS 4 & 5 npm install fail for bcrypt and db-migrate

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, gcc, npm, npm-install

Some time ago I installed NodeJS (v0.10.31) and worked on a project without problems, but just recently I decided to update to Node v5.0.0.
Everything was fine until I decided to use bcrypt and db-migrate. Calling the command **npm install** would fail spitting out a long list of details but no clear information about the problem:

```
$ sudo npm install

> bcrypt@0.8.5 install /home/cavpollo/intuitiva/cirio/cirio-id/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/cavpollo/intuitiva/cirio/cirio-id/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/bcrypt_node/src.o
In file included from /home/cavpollo/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node.h:42:0,
                 from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:24,
                 from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
/home/cavpollo/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/v8.h:336:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
/home/cavpollo/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/v8.h:469:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
/home/cavpollo/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/v8.h:856:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:184:0,
                 from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:13:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:16:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:19:12: error: ‘Maybe’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:24:12: error: ‘Maybe’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:31:1: error: ‘MaybeLocal’ does not name a type
...
[about 100 lines of log errors]
...
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:36:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/cavpollo/intuitiva/cirio/cirio-id/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-37-generic-pae
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/cavpollo/intuitiva/cirio/cirio-id/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-37-generic-pae
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.5 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/cavpollo/intuitiva/cirio/cirio-id/npm-debug.log
```

It doesnt seem to be any info on the web about the error, and using NodeJS V4.X.X didnt help at all either.

My setup:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- node v5.0.0
- npm  v3.3.10

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After much google searching, somebody pointed out that for NodeJS V4 (and newer versions) a newer version of GCC is needed (4.8 I think).

My current version was a 4.6.3 as you can see:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

So all it took was updating it, and was able to do it with the help of these links:

[How to install Gcc 4.8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8)

[How do I use the latest GCC 4.9 on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-4-9-on-ubuntu-14-04)

The sequence of commands I ended up using were:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8
```

Checking again the GCC version

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1
```

After that I was able to call 'npm install' and things went on flawlessly.

Comment: @MohitSoni Yay =D I'm glad it did

Comment: Thanks for posting.   Upgrading to V5 on ubuntu and had same problem. This worked like a charm.

Comment: Thank you, spent hours googling. Reinstalled, node, npm, node-gyp and many others to no avail. This worked a treat!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I go around about 4 hours with a lot of solution, only this work for me!

Answer (score 3):

This single line of update worked for me. Found the answer from this link https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/issues/351

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential

Then install bcrypt:

npm install bcrypt
```

Comment: This package updates gcc. That might be the reason it works

Answer (score 0):

Worked a treat thanks.

Updating NodeJS from v0.12.6 to 5.0.0
http://simon.fearby.com/blog/?p=2246